# Java Azure SDK scaleset: how to specify image version

Tags: java, azure, azure-vm-scale-set

When I am scaling up a scaleset I want to specify the image version to use. Right now it always uses the latest image from the compute gallery. I think that is what this az CLI command does: `az vmss update -- resource-group myResourceGroup --name myScaleSet --set virtualMachineProfile.storageProfile.imageReference.version=0.235.102011129`

Now I want to do the same in Java with the Azure Resource Manager SDK. ChatGPT gave this suggestion

```
// Resource group and scale set names
final String resourceGroupName = "myResourceGroup";
final String scaleSetName = "myScaleSet";

// Retrieve the scale set
VirtualMachineScaleSet scaleSet = azureResourceManager.virtualMachineScaleSets()
      .getByResourceGroup(resourceGroupName, scaleSetName);

// Update the image reference version
VirtualMachineScaleSetUpdate updateParams = scaleSet.update()
      .withVirtualMachineProfileStorageProfile(new VirtualMachineScaleSetUpdateStorageProfile()
              .withImageReference(new ImageReference()
              .withVersion("0.235.102011129")))
      .apply();
```

But the problem is that `withVirtualMachineProfileStorageProfile` does not exist for `scaleSet.update()`.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtual-machine-scale-sets/update?view=rest-compute-2023-10-02&tabs=Java#virtualmachinescaleset_update_maximumset_gen) which calls Azure Resource manager API with JAVA and updates Image with specific version by accessing StorageProfile of the VMSS:-

***Code Reference from MS Document:-***

```java
VirtualMachineScaleSetUpdateStorageProfile()
                            .withImageReference(new ImageReference()
                                .withId("hhhhhhhhh").withPublisher("MicrosoftWindowsServer")
                                .withOffer("WindowsServer").withSku("2016-Datacenter").withVersion("latest")
                                .withSharedGalleryImageId("aaaaaa"))
                            .withOsDisk(new VirtualMachineScaleSetUpdateOSDisk().withCaching(CachingTypes.READ_WRITE)
                                .withWriteAcceleratorEnabled(true).withDiskSizeGB(6)
                                .withImage(new VirtualHardDisk().withUri(
                                    "http://{existing-storage-account-name}.blob.core.windows.net/{existing-container-name}/myDisk.vhd"))
```

**sample.java:-**

```java
import com.azure.resourcemanager.compute.models.*;

public final class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        VirtualMachineScaleSetUpdateStorageProfile storageProfile = new VirtualMachineScaleSetUpdateStorageProfile()
            .withImageReference(new ImageReference()
                .withId("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa")
                .withPublisher("MicrosoftWindowsServer")
                .withOffer("WindowsServer")
                .withSku("2016-Datacenter")
                .withVersion("latest")
                .withSharedGalleryImageId("hshshs"))
            .withOsDisk(new VirtualMachineScaleSetUpdateOSDisk()
                .withCaching(CachingTypes.READ_WRITE)
                .withWriteAcceleratorEnabled(true)
                .withDiskSizeGB(6)
                .withImage(new VirtualHardDisk()
                    .withUri("http://{existing-storage-account-name}.blob.core.windows.net/{existing-container-name}/myDisk.vhd")));
    }
}
```